# MVC3 call SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

This is something that I would expect to be simple but it is not working. I simply want to be able to create stored procedures in my SQL Server DB and call them from within my MVC3 web app. I have managed to get my SPs imported into a generated function but when I call this I get an error:

The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'dbname.school_accreditation'. A member of the type, 'school_accreditation_id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I have created a stored procedure within SQL Server.

```
USE [mydb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DeleteSchoolAccreditations]    Script Date: 02/07/2014 20:56:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteSchoolAccreditations] 
@school_id int
AS

DELETE FROM [dbo].[school_accreditation]
 WHERE school_id = @school_id
```

The generated c# function to call the SP.

```
public virtual ObjectResult<school_accreditation> DeleteSchoolAccreditations(Nullable<int> school_id)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(typeof(school_accreditation).Assembly);

        var school_idParameter = school_id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("school_id", school_id) :
            new ObjectParameter("school_id", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<school_accreditation>("DeleteSchoolAccreditations", school_idParameter);
    }
```

Should I need to do anything to this generated method in order to get it to work. I am passing in an int to the method and it all looks okay when I debug.

Please any help would be greatly received.

Joe

Comment: Well, it would help if you understood which technology you were using.  MVC doesn't have any functionality whatsoever for data access.  You can use any data access technology you want with it.  You appear to be using Entity Framework, which is NOT MVC.

Comment: That's a fair point. I should have been more explicit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored preocedure does not return a school_accreditation entity.  Since it's a delete, it only returns the number of rows affected.  However, your stored preocedure ExecuteFucntion seems to want a return type of school_accreditation.

Obviously you did something wrong when you generated your sproc method.  Did you, by any chance, alter the sproc after you generated it?  If so, delete the method from your edmx and re-add it.

For something like this, it may just be simpler to do the call directly.  Something like `MyContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DeleteSchoolAccreditations", school_id);`

Comment: That makes perfect sense. So it's either my stored procedure which is wrong (I assume you would have noticed this, therefore I can assume it's okay) or, like you said I made a mistake. Either way thank you soo much. I will work it out!